# C# MVC 5 Cambiar Base de datos Sql Server a MySql (ApplicationSignInManager)

Tags: c#, mvc

Hola quisiera saber si existe forma de cambiar la bd default para autentificación de usuarios que viene por defecto en las aplicaciones MVC.

```
<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-WebApplication1-20190904104700.mdf;Initial Catalog=aspnet-WebApplication1-20190904104700;Integrated Security=True"
  providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Ya intente cambiarle la conexion pero no funciona (ya agregue el .dll de Mysql)

```
<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Server = localhost; database =deneb; UID = root; password =;" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Supongo que le tengo que mover algo al código, intente lo de esta pagina pero me salen muchos errores :(

[How to use MySQL for your ASP.NET Identity provider](https://insidemysql.com/how-to-use-mysql-for-your-asp-net-identity-provider-with-a-custom-primary-key/)

por ejemplo como este entre otros
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si alguien me pudiera ayudar se lo agradecería.

Comment: ¿Qué dice el error?

Comment: "No se encuentra el proveedor de datos .Net framework solicitado. Puede que no esté instalado." ¿Has intentado conectar a la BD de MySQL ?

Comment: Si, si hago una conexion con MySqlConnection(connectionString) si funciona pero para la autentificación no funciona

Comment: porque tienes que recrear la bd

Comment: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/51372.asp-net-mvc-5-code-first-migration-with-entity-framework-and-mysql.aspx

Comment: El problema es que por defecto crea la autentificación de usuarios en  Sql Server pero quieren la base de datos en Mysql

Comment: En otras palabras, ¿quieren los logins de los usuarios del SQL Server para manejar datos en el MySQL?

Comment: Si se podría decir.

Comment: ¿O te refieres a que quieren los usuarios que están dentro de las tablas generadas por asp net identity?

Comment: Las tablas que se generan en Sql server se generen en Mysql

Comment: ¿Has agregado Entity Framework compatible con MySQL ?

Comment: Para eso es MySQL Entity no? ya lo puse y no.

Comment: ¿Sabes cómo funciona Entity Framework? ¿Ese proyecto es nuevo? Me refiero a que si la data es sólo de desarrollo.

Answer (score 0):

Hay varios pasos y librerias que deberas agregar para poder usar `Identity` con `MySql`

[ASP.NET Identity: Using MySQL Storage with an EntityFramework MySQL Provider (C#)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/identity/overview/getting-started/aspnet-identity-using-mysql-storage-with-an-entityframework-mysql-provider)

En el articulo crea una db en Azure, pero si tienes tu propia db esa parte puedes obviarla.

Ahora bien el primer punto seria que tengas la libreria de Mysql que la agregas usando nuget

```
MySql.Data.Entity
```

Es importante definir la seccion de configuracion

```
<connectionStrings>
   <add name="DefaultConnection"
    providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient"
    connectionString="connection string"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

Si necesitas extender el model podras hacerlo ya que migrations aplicara los cambios

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework;
using System.Data.Entity;

namespace IdentityMySQLDemo.Models
{

  public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
  {
  }

  public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
  {
    static ApplicationDbContext()
    {
      Database.SetInitializer(new MySqlInitializer());
    }

    public ApplicationDbContext()
      : base("DefaultConnection")
    {
    }
  }
}
```

valida como define un `dbcontext` simple usando `ApplicationUser`

Despues usas las clases que ya existen para recuperar, no necesitas personalizar nada como lo haces con `Create()`